# Is it possible to specify language syntax highlighting mode on a per file basis in Atom?

Tags: emacs, atom-editor

In Emacs the [major mode for a file can be specified in a comment in the file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).  Is it possible to set the syntax highlighting mode in Atom using a comment in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible with the default-installed packages, no. The [file-mode package](https://atom.io/packages/file-mode) offers this capability.

Comment: Bummer on 2 counts, that the feature doesn't exist, and that I may have just volunteered... 8)